# Angular 2 RC5 routing setup, redirects to root after navigating to child route from code

Tags: angular

I have my route setup like the following:

```
const routes: Routes = [
...CoreRoutes,
{ path: 'error', component: ErrorPage},
{ path: 'login', component: LoginPage},
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'app/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'app/dashboard'},
];
```

with child routes (CoreRoutes) as:

```
export const CoreRoutes: Routes = [{
path: 'app',
component: Core,
children: [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: Dashboard},
  { path: 'another-page', component: AnotherPage},
  { path: 'maps-vector', component: MapsVector},
  { path: 'discuss1', component: Discuss1},
  { path: 'profile', component: Profile},
  { path: 'discuss2', component: Discuss2},
  { path: 'grid', component: Grid},
  { path: 'service/:service', component: DynamoComponent},
  { path: 'dynamo', component: DynamoComponent},
  { path: 'tables/dynamic', component: TablesDynamic}
]
```

}];

when I start the app it redirects to 'app/dashboard' correctly, but when I navigate using code from my dynamo view

```
this.router.navigate(['app/service/', encodedParams]);
```

to app/service:service I can see it going to the correct route (and instantiating the component, but after its NavigationEnd it then redirects to the default 'app/dashboard'. I can only assume it is falling back to the default route, but can't figure out why it's doing it.

If I attempt to access app/service:service a second time after the redirect, it works.

If I remove the default route from the app routes, it then works correctly but I don't get the benefits of the default route.

I know it's probably something simple as I've only started using angular 2 recently, but I've been beating my head on this for quite some time and am at a loss why this route is behaving poorly and selecting the default route when it is successfully loading the child route.

None of the other routes have this issue, although this one route is the ony one that I am navigating using code, the others are using routerlinks on their pages

This is the information I am logging to the console from the navigation events showing the redirection to '/' after successfully finding the correct route app/service

```
Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
core.ts:246navigation end id: 1 url: /
core.ts:243 navigation start id: 2 url: /app/dynamo
core.ts:240 navigation routerecognized id: 2 url: /app/dynamo
core.ts:246 navigation end id: 2 url: /app/dynamo
core.ts:243 navigation start id: 3 url: /app/service/%257B...
core.ts:240 navigation routerecognized id: 3 url: /app/service/%257B...
core.ts:246 navigation end id: 3 url: /app/service/%257B.
core.ts:243 navigation start id: 4 url: /
core.ts:240 navigation routerecognized id: 4 url: /
core.ts:246 navigation end id: 4 url: /
```

Comment: what is `encodedParams` is it some object or a string number?

Comment: It's an encodedUrlComponent string which is acting as the parameter

Comment: I'd also mention that if I open the app directly to the
    /app/service/(encodedParams)
url in the browser as an initial url it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a forward slash in navigate.

```
  this.router.navigate(['/app/service/', encodedParams]);
```

Notice forward slash `/` before `app/service/ -> /app/service/`

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I tried that, it has problems either way, in the same way. First access redirects, second access and following successful.

Comment: I've debugged it to the point of when the second erroneous navigation is subscribed to router.navigate but haven't been able to figure out the source that sent the extra navigation. I'm assuming it is in the route reconciliation, but haven't gotten any deeper yet. I am hoping someone who has more experience can provide something quicker and simpler than me slogging through the route reconciliation code.

Comment: what is the URL which gets routed? can you create a simple Plunker for this issue?

Comment: I tried this and it works when you dont inbclude forward slash it takes it as a relative route and constructs the url like `app/dynamo/app/service/encodedURL` and when you use a forward slash it creates the URL like `app/service/encodedURL` which matches the path.

Comment: After finding a workaround I moved on to other things, but later figured out the issue.

I was initiating the process with an anchor tag with href ='#' and running a click event processor. Simply put, I wasn't returning false from that event processor so the click event was processed, route established, and then the anchor tag was redirecting to '#' like it was told to do :(. Stupid little things like this aggravate me, but it's all due to my own oversight.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I figured out the root issue, but I've found a way to work around it without really understanding why it works.

In the DynamoComponent it calls a data service, caches those results, generates a template for that data, then generates a component using the template and passes in the requested data. I'm thinking maybe its some type of data sync issue on the data populated cache objects between the original and the child component?

I am using a caching service in the app (on a parent object to insure global access), the anomaly I described was when I was using a MemoryStorage class that I wrote (paralleled by SessionStorage, LocalStorage, and NoStorage classes) to cache the results of the remote data, the first time through its should grab the data from the service, subsequently it should grab the data from memory cache. Even though the initial entry into the page '/service' using default value and no parameters works, the very next subsequent call with parameters did not, although all of those following worked after the first.

```
@Injectable()
export class MemoryStorage {

  private cached_data: { [key: string]: any } = {};

  constructor() {
  }

  public getItem(key: string) {
    return this.cached_data[key];
  }


  public setItem(key: string, value: any) {
    this.cached_data[key] = value;
  }

  public clear(key?: string){
    if (key)
        delete this.cached_data[key];
    else
        this.cached_data = {}; 
  }
}
```

The workaround that I found is to use session or local storage, although any pointers on why my MemoryStore might have syncing issues would be appreciated, since I can't always depend on session or local storage.

Also I'm really not sure why this would cause the route to go to the root route without generating any errors. Makes no sense, but I've verified it doesn't do it when using LocalStorage or SessionStorage, although it still has syncing issues using NoCache when making the service calls each time the data is needed.